Phy6252 sdk coding with keil
I know this is a beginner question, but I could use some help.
I’m trying to code using this SDK: https://github.com/sullivan986/phy6252-SDK, and I have a couple of questions:

To start a new project, should I just create a generic ARM Cortex-M0 project, or are there additional settings I need to configure?
I noticed that the BLE section in the driver folder only includes a header file. Is this normal, or am I missing something?


Such an SDK commonly comes with appropriate documentation, please [edit] your question to clarify what you found. And what did the repository's maintainer reply when you asked them?

The SDK "examples" folder includes uvprojx (Keil uVision) project files, I suggest you start there, and see how they are setup.  For example https://github.com/sullivan986/phy6252-SDK/tree/main/example/ble_central/simpleBleCentral
They do appear to be using the generic CM0 startup, but those files may be modified in the projects for the specific part.  You should compare those files (RTE/Device/ARMCM0) in the examples with the generic toolchain provided versions, or just replace them after project creation with those in the SDK.
The examples also include a scatter file defining the memory map of the part which is critical and not provided by the generic CM0 support.
However the example scatter files are unusual in that they specify an additional ROM region ER_ROM_XIP and explicitly locates specific object files and libraries in that region.  Looking at the datasheet, this region is an on-module SPI NOR flash with a controller that allows it to appear memory mapped. However the method the author has chosen seems a rather maintenance heavy and error prone solution.  Normally if a module requires explicit location you would do that with linker directives in the code rather than specifying modules which differ from project to project in the scatter file.
The ER_IROM1 region specified is in fact SRAM and having a .ANY (+RW +ZI) read/write allocation, it is inappropriately named.
I would suggest a more suitable scatter file would define LR_ROM_XIP thus:
LR_ROM_XIP  0x11020000 0x030000 {
  ER_ROM_XIP 0x11020000 0x030000  {  ; load address = execution address
   .ANY (+RO)
   *.o(_section_xip_code_)
  }
 }  

which could then be the same for each project. However I am not familiar with the part, so proceed with caution with respect to my advice on the scatter file. It is perhaps a concern however that the author does not appear to know what they are doing with respect to this file.
There are also some inexplicable holes in the scatter file defined memory map.  Normally you would specify the physical memory map in its entirety which looks like:

That is not done in the examples.  The author appears to have specified the RAM size required by the application since they differ in each scatter file.  That is just silly.  You should specify all available RAM and let the linker use what it will.
Some of the examples locate object code explicitly in a RAM region (still erroneously labelled IROM).  That is no doubt done for performance reasons, but it is generally far simpler to locate the modules via linker directives in the code than to maintain a different scatter file for each project.
Every scatter file in the SDK examples is tailored to the specific project for reasons that may not be entirely clear. I would recommend using a common scatter file for all projects that simply defines the physical layout and looks more like:
; *************************************************************
; *** Scatter-Loading Description File generated by uVision ***
; *************************************************************
LR_SRAM0 0x1fff0000 0x8000             ; SRAM0 32kb
{
  JUMP_TABLE 0x1fff0000 0x00400          
  {
    .ANY (jump_table_mem_area)         ; 1Kb jump table
  }

  GOLBAL_CONFIG 0x1fff0400 0x00400     ; 1Kb global configuration
  {
   .ANY (global_config_area) 
  }  
  
   *.o (RESET, +First)                 ; reset vector/start-up?
   *(InRoot$$Sections)                 ; root region section

   *.o(_section_sram_code_)            ; Anything explicitly located
                                       ; in RAM by linker directive 
                                       ; in code

   .ANY (+RW +ZI)                      ; Any data not explicitly 
                                       ; located
} 

LR_SRAM1 0x1fff8000 0x4000             ; SRAM1 16kb
{
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)                      ; Any data not explicitly 
                                       ; located
}

LR_SRAM2 0x1fffC000 0x4000             ; SRAM2 16kb
{
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)                      ; Any data not explicitly 
                                       ; located
}

LR_ROM_XIP  0x11000000 0x040000        ; 256K flash part 
                                       ; (0x080000 for 512K)
{
  ER_ROM_XIP 0x11000000 0x040000       ; Load Region == Exec Region
  {  
    .ANY (+RO)                         ; And code and RO data
    *.o(_section_xip_code_)            ; Explicitly located in XIP 
  }
} 

Then rather that specifying specific object code to place in SRAM or Flash you can do that at the function level with for example:
#pragma arm section code="_section_sram_code_"
void ram_function_example()
{
    ...
}

void another_ram_function_example()
{
    ...
}
#pragma arm section // restore default location

Or for individual functions:
__attribute__((section ("_section_xip_code_"))) void an_xip_function(void) 
{
    ...
}

Again I urge caution - the "holes" in the example scatter files may be there for a reason, but it is a bad idea not to make it explicit.  for example they all seem to avoid the first half of the XIP ) perhaps for OTA update storage, but I think is space is to be reserved for such things it is useful to make it explicit for documentation if nothing else, so you might for example have:
LR_ROM_XIP  0x11000000 0x040000        ; 256K flash part 
                                       ; (0x080000 for 512K)
{
  RESERVED_XIP 0x11000000 EMPTY 0x020000  ; Lower half 128K 
                                          ; Do not use
  {  
  }

  ER_ROM_XIP 0x11020000 0x020000       ; Upper half 128K
  {  
    .ANY (+RO)                         ; And code and RO data
    *.o(_section_xip_code_)            ; Explicitly located in XIP 
  }
} 

You can still of course customise the scatter for a particular project by adding entire object code modules in one section or another, but I suggest keeping that to a minimum.  For example when using third-party code that you do not want to modify.  And use SRAM location when only absolutely necessary to performance.
There is no real reason in the above for separating the SRAM0/1/2 and you could combine them:
LR_SRAM0 0x1fff0000 0x10000             ; SRAM 64kb
{
  JUMP_TABLE 0x1fff0000 0x00400          
  {
    .ANY (jump_table_mem_area)         ; 1Kb jump table
  }

  GOLBAL_CONFIG 0x1fff0400 0x00400     ; 1Kb global configuration
  {
   .ANY (global_config_area) 
  }  
  
   *.o (RESET, +First)                 ; reset vector/start-up?
   *(InRoot$$Sections)                 ; root region section

   *.o(_section_sram_code_)            ; Anything explicitly located
                                       ; in RAM by linker directive 
                                       ; in code

   .ANY (+RW +ZI)                      ; Any data not explicitly 
                                       ; located
} 

giving the linker more space to locate _section_sram_code_.  However in some cases there are advantages in distinguishing SRAM regions.  For example if they are on separate buses and can be accessed concurrently, it may improve performance for example to place DMA buffers in a separate SRAM block to other data to avoid bus contention. For that would would create another names section in a region and use linker directives to place DMA buffers as required. I have no idea whether there is any such advantage on this part.
Again I urge caution when deviating from the SDK author's scatter file s, but since they are all different for no clear reason and specific to each project, you will have to learn for your self how to create one, and I suggest that you start with a "works for all" generic template, and customise it as necessary for performance or functional reasons.
